# kvm_stat (EXTERNAL_INTERRUPT) counter meaning

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

We are running kvm_stat command to identify the source of vm_exits and trying to minimise it.

We are running a FreeBSD 8.4 VM with Intel XL710 40G NIC in polling mode (just like DPDK) on Fedora 24. Interrupts are disabled on the Intel 40G NIC.

When we took the output of `kvm_stat -1` command, we find that the following counter is high during data traffic. Since MSIX interrupts are disabled for the NIC, we do not expect it to increase:

```
kvm_exit(EXTERNAL_INTERRUPT)                   1728349     27738
```

The counter values comes down when traffic is not in progress.

```
uname -a
Linux nirmal 4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 12 11:50:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can you please explain what that counter "EXTERNAL_INTERRUPT" refers to.